# Asp.net timer causes full code restart on backend?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a timer in an updatepanel, every time the timer ticks the code restarts. I want the code and updatepanel to refresh individually. Here is the html code that causes full code restart:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelMain" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick">
                </asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer runat="server" id="Timer1" interval="3000" ontick="OnTimedEvent" />
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelMain" runat="server">
```

Comment: There will always be a full code restart. If you do not want that, you need to use an Ajax solution and not an UpdatePanel.

Comment: Details please?

Comment: Well, even if an UPdatePanel is triggered the whole page code will be executed like it would when you reload the entire page. But only the changes in the UI will be send to the client when using an UpdatePanel.

Comment: I still don't understand how to fix this

Comment: ASP.Net magic for beginners :-)